# Why can't I pipeline functions with explicit types

Tags: f#

I'm F# beginner

Works:

```
let add x y = x + y
let x : decimal = 2 |> add 3
```

Doesn't work:

```
let add (x : decimal, y : decimal) = x + y
let x : decimal = 2m |> add 3m
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `(x : decimal, y : decimal)` is a tuple of two decimals. And signature of your function is `decimal * decimal -> decimal`. I.e. it accepts single parater (tuple) and returns decimal value.

You need to pass two parameters instead: `(x : decimal) (y : decimal)`

```
let add (x : decimal) (y : decimal) = x + y // decimal -> decimal -> decimal
let x = 2m |> add 3m
```

Remember, if you see `,` in F# then you are looking at tuple. Comma is not used as a parameter delimiter here.